# Returning a remainder

Tags: java

```
@Test
public void testCheckDigit()
{
    ZipCode z7 = new ZipCode (12345);
    assertEquals(5, z7.getCheckDigit());
    ZipCode z8 = new ZipCode (01234);
    assertEquals(0, z8.getCheckDigit());
    ZipCode z9 = new ZipCode (11234);
    assertEquals(9, z9.getCheckDigit());
    ZipCode z10 = new ZipCode (10044);
    assertEquals(1, z10.getCheckDigit());
}
```

---

```
public int getCheckDigit()
{

while(zipCode > 0)
{
    digitCheck = digitCheck + zipCode % 10;
    zipCode = zipCode / 10;
    digitCheck = digitCheck % 10;

}

return digitCheck;
```

So whenever I run the test it is supposed to return the number that would make the individual numbers all added up in ZipCode a clean division of 10, but when its supposed to return 9 it returns 1 instead. What is going wrong with my code?

Comment: Note that integers starting with `0` are interpreted in octal: `01234` isn't the number you perhaps think it is.

Comment: Also: you probably don't want to actually mutate the `zipCode` member variable, since that leaves it at zero afterwards.

Comment: I'm not having trouble with the one that begins with zero it returns what i want it to I'm having trouble with 11234 returning as 9, and for what I'm doing with this i don't really need to worry about zipCode being changed to zero but i understand what you are saying

Comment: (And you shouldn't be mutating the `digitCheck` member variable either)

Comment: Why do you expect `11234` to be 9? `1+1+2+3+4=11; 11%10=1`.

Comment: So with zip codes they add up for the check digit and its supposed to return the digit that would make 11 add up to 20, I'm not sure what fix i would need to do to my code to make the border cases work though

Comment: Oh. So you need to do `(10 - digitCheck) % 10` or something like that at the end.

Comment: Yeah i already tried that by having an if statement that if the remainder came out to be more than 10 it would do basically the same thing as that it still returns 1

Comment: Nope: if `digitCheck` is 9 after the loop, that converts it to 1. And the remainder can't be more than 9, because of the `digitCheck = digitCheck % 10;` line.

Comment: So then why does my 10044 return with 9 when its supposed to be returning 1?

Comment: Because you've not added the `(10 - digitCheck) % 10` after the loop.

Comment: Whenever I do that it makes the numbers that do not add up to over ten return the wrong value